# Cannot assign value of type '()' to type 'CallbackBlock!'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am trying to do something in View Controller when an event happens in GameViewController.

So this is what I do

In GameViewController

```
        typealias CallbackBlock = () -> Void

        public class GameController {
            var onAnagramSolved : CallbackBlock!


    func inSomeMethod(){
       self.onAnagramSolved()
    }
 }
```

In ViewController

```
public class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var gameController: GameController!


    public override func loadView() {
        super.loadView()

            gameController = GameController()
    }


    override  public func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // This is where I get the error (which is the title)
        gameController.onAnagramSolved = self.showLevelMenu()

    }



   func showLevelMenu(){
     // A method showing  UIAlertController

   }
```

But then I get the Error saying

```
Cannot assign a value of type '()' to type 'CallbackBlock!'
```

Its in Swift 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the `()` after the method name. That is, changing this line:

```
gameController.onAnagramSolved = self.showLevelMenu()
```

to this:

```
gameController.onAnagramSolved = self.showLevelMenu
```

The first syntax is for a *function call* and the other one is for a *function reference* (i.e., produces a reference to a given function).

A more explicit option would be to use a *closure* instead:

```
gameController.onAnagramSolved = { self.showLevelMenu() }
```